# Cauchy-Schwarz applied multiple times with difficulty on second application

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Below, $a_i$ is a column vector with matching dimension as the square matrix $G$ and $b_{ij}$ is a scalar. I apply CS once over $(i,j)$ to obtain the first inequality but I'd like to apply CS once more to the first term on the right hand side, to basically decompose the bound into the Euclidean norm of the matrix $G$ and the norm of the vector $a$.

$$\sum_i^N \sum_j^N a_{i}'\,G \,a_{j} \cdot b_{ij} \leq \left(\sum_i^N\sum_j^N \left[ a_{i}'G a_{j}\right]^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \left(\sum_i^N\sum_j^N b_{ij}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: So for all $i$, $a_i$ is a vector, right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Alright then you can just refer to my answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do. Notice that if $x$ and $y$ are two vectors we have by Cauchy-Schwarz

$$
\begin{aligned}
(x^T G y)^2 &= \left(\sum_{k,l} G_{kl} x_k y_l\right)^2
\leq \underbrace{\left(\sum_{k,l} G_{kl}^2 \right)}_{\|G\|^2} \left(\sum_{k,l} x_k^2 y_l^2 \right) \\
&= \|G\|^2 \left(\sum_k x_k^2 \right) \left(\sum_l y_l^2 \right) = \|G\|^2 \|x\|^2 \|y\|^2
\end{aligned}
$$

so applying this with $x = a_i$, $y = a_j$ in your case you get

$$
\sum_{i,j} (a_i^T G a_j)^2  \leq
\sum_{i,j} \|G\|^2 \|a_i\|^2 \|a_j\|^2 = \|G\|^2 \left(\sum_i \|a_i\|^2\right)^2 = \|G\|^2 \|a\|^4
$$

so

$$
\left(\sum_{i,j} (a_i^T G a_j)^2 \right)^{1/2} \leq
\|G\| \|a\|^2
$$

if you consider $a$ as a matrix or a long vector for the last equality. Hope this helps!

Comment: You have $\sum_i \|a_i \|^2 = \sum_i \sum_j a_{i,j}^2$ so whether you call $a$ the 'long' vector of $\mathbb R^{N^2}$ where you have piled up all the $a_i$'s, or the $N \times N$ matrix whose $i$-th column is $a_i$ (and use the Frobenius norm), you have $\sum_i \|a_i \|^2 = \sum_i \sum_j a_{i,j}^2 = \| a\|^2$. Both of these definitions of $a$ are equivalent because using the Frobenius norm $\|M\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} m_{i,j}^2}$ on the space of $N \times N$ matrices is exactly like considering an $N \times N$ matrix as a vector of $\mathbb R^{N^2}$

Comment: Thank you @DodoDuQuercy. Just confirming: what do you mean by consider $a$ as a matrix or long vector? $a_i$ is a vector, so are you considering $a$ as the stacked version of $a_i$?

Comment: I see, thank you for the very clear explanation!

Comment: Again thank you.